# Come back to the activity without creating a new one after onItemClick on a ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have an option menu in my app that shows a list of all the markers that user added on the map. Markers are represented using a ListView, and when user selects one of the items of that ListView, I want to go back (resume?) to the main activity passing the marker position as a parameter, but without creating a new activity. Is that possible? Now I am creating a new activity when user clicks on any item, is it possible to simply come back to the main activity?

Code of MarkersList activity:

```
mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id)
    {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
        MyMarkerObj marker = (MyMarkerObj)table.get(position);
        intent.putExtra("position", marker.getId());
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
});
```

Code of MainActivity:

```
 @Override
protected void onResume() {  

    Intent intent = getIntent(); 
    if (intent != null) { 
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            int reportId = bundle.getInt("position");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Integer.toString(reportId), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              try {
                data.open();
               } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("hello", "hello");
               } 


            //Get the marker selected in the listview
            String position = data.getMarkerById(reportId);
            //System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>> position = " + position); 
        }
    }
    super.onResume();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `StartActivityForResult(intent,reqcode)` instead of `startActivity(intent)`.

first in your 
First Activity

```
Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this, MarkerActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i,1);  <-- 1 is request code, you can give anything.
```

and then on ItemClick of second Activity

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
    MyMarkerObj marker = (MyMarkerObj)table.get(position);
    intent.putExtra("position", marker.getId());
   setResult(responsecode,intent);
    finish();
```

And in

onActivityForResult of FirstActivity

get the value like this

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
     if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {

       Bundle bun=data.getExtras();
       int position= bun.getInt("position");     
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand...so, should I use "setResult(marker.getId(),intent);" instead of "intent.putExtra("position", marker.getId());" to add the parameter so that the MainActivity can read it?

Comment: And should I call onActivityResult from the MainActivity?

Comment: @Alberto If you want to transfer value, put in the intent extra like What I have showed in the above, check my edit..

Comment: @Alberto yes..it is the overriden method when you press onActivity and then `ctrl+space` it will show that..Do the same as I have shown in the answer.. read answer twice or thrice to understand.. and for more details search in google about StartActivityForResult