# How can I go back to main activity after selecting an option from my listview activity

Tags: java, android

I have two activities one is main activity and another is having list of cities. I want to go back to main activity when i choose any option from the second activity.
i am attaching the screen shots of my activities.
please help me
thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: simply onItemclick finish the current activity

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Come back to the activity without creating a new one after onItemClick on a ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089468/come-back-to-the-activity-without-creating-a-new-one-after-onitemclick-on-a-list)

Comment: @Shahbaz Siddiqui from your reputation it seems you're new on this site. Please read the site how to ask a good question on Stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

**You should read about [Activity class](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/components/activities.html)**

Activity class in Android has method

```
        startActivityForResult();
```

You should use it
And `onClick()` listner in your second Activity(list)
Where you will `setResult()` and will `finish()` your activity with list

Answer (score 1):

You have three ways to do that

1. finish your current acitvity by calling `finish()`
2. go back to the main activity by calling `onBackPressed()`
3. go to the main activity by calling 
   `Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
   startActivityForResult(i, 1);`

You can put one of them inside your click event

Answer (score 0):

If you simply need to go back use this:

```
myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
        long arg3) 
  {
     finish();
  }
});
```

if you need something to be passed to the first activity, you can call from mainActivity the `startActivityForResult()`, [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) is the doc.